# Cannot reach server

Tags: windows, networking

I have a problem with a server. Sometimes I can see PING requests, sometimes I can't. 
My colleagues don't have this problem.
I am on the same domain as the server. When I can't reach it by name or by IP address, I've checked my ARP table and it's still okay.

I don't know what to check now. I know nobody can tell me what's wrong already, but could you give me some advice on what to check?

Here is the `ipconfig/all` result:

```
Configuration IP de Windows

   Nom de l'hôte . . . . . . . . . . : SHUTTLE-2
   Suffixe DNS principal . . . . . . : EXPERIA.local
   Type de noeud. . . . . . . . . .  : Hybride
   Routage IP activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Proxy WINS activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Liste de recherche du suffixe DNS.: EXPERIA.local

Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : EXPERIA.local
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 80-EE-73-1F-E2-79
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::9d74:2338:9619:cd7e%11(préféré
)
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.104(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Bail obtenu. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : lundi 22 juin 2015 09:37:29
   Bail expirant. . . . . . . . . . . . . : mardi 30 juin 2015 12:33:20
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   Serveur DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 243330675
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-85-1F-51-80-EE-73-1F-E2
-79
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
                                       208.67.222.222
                                       208.67.220.220
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé

Carte Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapte
r
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-48-DD
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::9ced:58de:900e:683d%13(préféré
)
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.56.1(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 386400295
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-85-1F-51-80-EE-73-1F-E2
-79
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé

Carte Tunnel isatap.EXPERIA.local :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : EXPERIA.local
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carte Microsoft ISATAP
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Tunnel Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Tunnel isatap.{DCD7ED18-5D03-417F-B148-273ECF1F9E07} :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carte Microsoft ISATAP #2
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
```

Comment: Maybe it's useful to do an **IPConfig /All** and post the results so we can actually help you.

Comment: @Arsnow : Did you checked after disabling you antivirus/firewall?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention it, yes, i tried to disable my firewall and my antivirus